# Slider in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, scipy, slider

I am trying to make a slider for the second graph. I succeeded in making the slider, but I am having trouble with the function that is supposed to update the values of the y data. Can someone please help me see my mistake?
Thank you

Code is:

````
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
from scipy.constants import *

%matplotlib tk 


#Defining constants and variables of interests
hbar_sq = hbar**2
omega_0 = 5.63*10**14 #Transition of 532 nm in the visible, expressed in hertz (delta E/hbar)
omega = 5.65*10**14   #Incoming laser of 530 nm in the visible, expressed in hertz
diff = omega_0 - omega #The difference in frequency between the incoming field and the state-to-state frequency
diff_p=abs(diff)
V = np.sqrt((diff**2 * hbar_sq)) #Matrix element value
V_sq=V**2
t=np.linspace(0,(8*pi/diff_p),100)
P=(V_sq/(hbar_sq*diff**2))*np.sin(diff*t/2)*np.sin(diff*t/2)

#Plot parameters
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.subplots()
f=ax.plot(t,P,'b')
plt.ylabel('P (t)')
plt.xlabel('time')

#Second part, plotting P(omega)
omega1=np.linspace(4.99*10**14,6.66*10**14,100)
diff1=omega_0-omega1
P1=(V_sq/(hbar_sq*diff1**2))*np.sin(diff1*t/2)*np.sin(diff1*t/2)

#Plot parameters
fig1=plt.figure()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25) #Generating some space under the graph to add the slider button
ax1=fig1.subplots()
f1=ax1.plot(omega1,P1)

#Adding slider functionality to plot
# xposition, yposition, width and height
ax1.slide = plt.axes([0.15,0.1,0.65,0.05])
#Properties of the slider
df = Slider(ax1.slide,'driving frequency',valmin=4.99*10**14, valmax=6.66*10**14, valinit=6.66*10**14, valstep=.5*10**14)

#Making a function to update the plot
def update(val):
    current_v = df.val
    omega1 = np.linspace(4.99*10**14,current_v,100)
    P1=(V_sq/(hbar_sq*diff1**2))*np.sin(diff1*t/2)*np.sin(diff1*t/2)
    f1.set_ydata(P1)
    fig1.canvas.draw()
df.on_changed(update)
plt.show()```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited your `update()` function like this:

```
def update(val):
    current_v = df.val
    omega1 = np.linspace(4.99*10**14,current_v,100)
    P1=(V_sq/(hbar_sq*diff1**2))*np.sin(diff1*t/2)*np.sin(diff1*t/2)
    ax1.cla()
    ax1.plot(omega1, P1)
    ax1.set_xlim(4.5e14, 6.5e14)
```

First of all, I clear the previous plot with `ax1.cla()`, then I plot the new curve with `ax1.plot(omega1, P1)`.
Optionally, you can fix the x-axis limits with `ax1.set_xlim(4.5e14, 6.5e14)`, in order to keep fixed the axis and see the curve changing. Moreover, I suggest to call the function `update(df.val)` before showing the figure, in order to fix the axis as soon as the figure is shown, even before the user changes the slider value.

### Complete Code

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
from scipy.constants import *

%matplotlib tk 


#Defining constants and variables of interests
hbar_sq = hbar**2
omega_0 = 5.63*10**14 #Transition of 532 nm in the visible, expressed in hertz (delta E/hbar)
omega = 5.65*10**14   #Incoming laser of 530 nm in the visible, expressed in hertz
diff = omega_0 - omega #The difference in frequency between the incoming field and the state-to-state frequency
diff_p=abs(diff)
V = np.sqrt((diff**2 * hbar_sq)) #Matrix element value
V_sq=V**2
t=np.linspace(0,(8*pi/diff_p),100)
P=(V_sq/(hbar_sq*diff**2))*np.sin(diff*t/2)*np.sin(diff*t/2)

#Plot parameters
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.subplots()
f=ax.plot(t,P,'b')
plt.ylabel('P (t)')
plt.xlabel('time')

#Second part, plotting P(omega)
omega1=np.linspace(4.99*10**14,6.66*10**14,100)
diff1=omega_0-omega1
P1=(V_sq/(hbar_sq*diff1**2))*np.sin(diff1*t/2)*np.sin(diff1*t/2)

#Plot parameters
fig1=plt.figure()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25) #Generating some space under the graph to add the slider button
ax1=fig1.subplots()
f1=ax1.plot(omega1,P1)

#Adding slider functionality to plot
# xposition, yposition, width and height
ax1.slide = plt.axes([0.15,0.1,0.65,0.05])
#Properties of the slider
df = Slider(ax1.slide,'driving frequency',valmin=4.99*10**14, valmax=6.66*10**14, valinit=6.66*10**14, valstep=.5*10**13)

#Making a function to update the plot
def update(val):
    current_v = df.val
    omega1 = np.linspace(4.99*10**14,current_v,100)
    P1=(V_sq/(hbar_sq*diff1**2))*np.sin(diff1*t/2)*np.sin(diff1*t/2)
    ax1.cla()
    ax1.plot(omega1, P1)
    ax1.set_xlim(4.5e14, 6.5e14)
df.on_changed(update)
update(df.val)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Andrea!!! I am so appreciative of your help

Comment: Just did! Thank you again!